# Investigating colour of a star when in motion

Tags: special-relativity, time, inertial-frames, stars, doppler-effect

The star Alpha Centauri is 4 light years from Earth. For an astronaut travelling at $c/2$ from
Earth to Alpha Centauri. So, this apparently means 
The colour of a distant star perpendicular to the direction of travel is different than as
seen from Earth due to time dilation. 
I don't understand this, please help

Comment: "perpendicular" in which reference frame?

Comment: It's a bit complicated... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect I *think* you're asking about the transverse Doppler effect, but you should clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit in this question is the fact that the Planck blackbody spectrum:

$$B(\nu, T) = \frac{2h\nu^3}{c^2}\frac 1 {e^{\frac{h\nu}{kT}}-1} $$

at temperature $T$, when boosted, remains a blackbody spectrum, albeit for a different temperature.

In the interest of simplicity, though, consider a monochromatic star that emmits one frequency, $\nu$, in its rest frame (which is also the rest frame of the Earth and Alpha Centauri). The star fills its slice of spacetime (aka: space) with photons described by:

$$k^{\mu} = (\omega/c, {\bf \vec k})  = (k, k_x, k_y, k_z)$$

where $\omega = 2\pi\nu = kc$ is the frequency (color), ${\bf \hat k}$ points back to the star, and $k\equiv ||{\bf \vec k}||$.

An observer moving at ${\bf \vec v}=v{\bf \hat z}$ through this sea of radially emitted, monochromatic light, sees it Doppler shifted, per:

$$k'^{\mu}=(\gamma[k-\frac v ck_z],k_x, k_y, \gamma[k_z-\frac v ck])$$

If the star's location is orthogonal to the direction of travel, $k_z=0$. We can also chose the axis such that $k_y=0$, and  thus  $k_x=k$:

$$k'^{\mu}=(\gamma k, k, 0, -\gamma \frac v ck)$$

The astronaut sees a frequency (color):

$$ \omega' = k'_0c = \gamma\omega $$

This is the transverse Doppler effect at closest geometric approach.

The fact that there is a factor of $\gamma$ may lead someone to say "it's time dilation", but it's really just "the relativistic doppler shift", in which time dilation and length contraction are inexorably mixed.

Note that in this approach, the source was not really relevant. The photon was treated as a free particle with a 4-wave-vector that is entirely frame dependent, all the "source" did was tie that down in one reference frame, so that it could be boosted to another.

Also: note that there is *another* transverse Doppler shift (at closest visual approach) in which $k_z' = 0$, where you will find:

$$ \omega' = \omega / \gamma $$

in which case one may be more tempted to say "it's all time dilation" (It's not: it's part time-dilation and part stellar aberration...which together *are* the relativistic Doppler effect).

Answer (score 0):

If an astronaut is travelling towards, away or just past a monochromatic source of radiation, due to dilation of this astronauts clock (and the astronaut turns into a dawdler himself) this source changes color indeed, since frequency of this source's radiation changes.

What frequency would *moving observer* measure? For an answer let's look into the famous [1905 Albert Einstein paper, § 7.](http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_1905_relativity.pdf)

*“From the equation for $\omega‘ $ it follows that if an observer is moving with velocity $v$ relatively to an infinitely distant source of light of frequency $\nu$, in such a way that the connecting line “source - observer” makes the angle $\phi$ with the velocity of the observer referred to a system of coordinates which is at rest relatively to the source of light, the frequency $\nu‘$ of the light perceived by the observer is given by the equation":*

$$\nu‘=  \nu \frac {(1-\cos\phi \cdot v/c)}{\sqrt {1-v^2/c^2}}$$

*This is Doppler’s principle for any velocities whatever.”*

If an observer is moving towards or away from the source, there are longitudinal and transverse contributions into the relativistic Doppler effect. At their (frame independent) points of closest approach $(\cos\phi = 0)$ with the source the moving observer would measure $\gamma$ times higher frequency of light. If this observer was moving with velocity close to that of light, the "yellow" star would appear to him "violet", because all processes outside his spacecraft would appear to him as if in "fast forward" mode.  This effect is known as transverse Doppler effect in source's frame, it is purely due to contribution of time dilation.

At point of closest approach the *moving observer* would see the source not in its actual position, but in front of him at the angle $\sin \theta = v/c$. The moving observer would explain  displacement of apparent position of the source by relativistic aberration of light.

Change of frame does not affect measured relativistic Doppler effect; one can analyze it in the observer's frame. Color of the star will still be the same, but interpretation is a bit different. In this case we can assign time dilation to the moving source, or the star. Apparent displacement of the source in this case would be due to light - time correction, or light propagation delay.

The relativistic aberration of light was clearly explained in the Feynman Lectures, [Relativistic Effects in Radiation, 34-8](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_34.html).

Answer (score 0):

The Doppler effect happens to sound waves too. If we move towards the source, the picth (frequency) increases. If we move away from it the pitch decreases. If we move away quick enough, we can't hear anything because our speed is faster that the coming wave.

The difference with light is that its speed is always the same no matter how fast we move. And the consequence is that not only the frequency, but also the wavelength changes.